# How do I remove the dash (-) between my Site Title and Tagline?

Tags: themes, title

I want my site logo to look like the second image rather than the first. However, when I do the settings in the second image, the site is displayed as "Example - Site" in bookmarks and Google search results rather than "Example Site". Aside from looking bad, this is also terrible for SEO. How can I get the site to look like the second image while displaying the site's title as "Example Site"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The "Tagline" isn't the second word of your site/business name. It's a *tagline*. It makes no sense to use it as part of the site name. If you want your site name to look different, upload a logo image. Regardless, you seem to be using WordPress.com. This is a forum for discussing development with the WordPress software.

Comment: I am not using WordPress.com, I am using Bluehost. And even if I were using WordPress.com this is still an issue with the Wordpress software itself. I want the aesthetic of the second image, but that can only be accomplished by making "Example" the title and "Site" the tagline (which I do not want). Taking a screenshot and using that as a logo is definitely possible, but it would not be professional or optimized.

Comment: How is it not professional? I guarantee you that 90%+ of the websites you've ever visited had image logos. Anyway, even if you're using Bluehost (who apparently custom style the customiser?), it's still not a WordPress software issue, it's your theme. Your theme has opted to display the site title and tagline like that. Having the hyphen between the name and tagline in the title is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little bit if you use a SEO plugin (in most of them the appearance of the title (what you see in bookmarks and Google) is just a setting) or which theme you are using. In some of the themes you also have a setting for the title, in other you would have to go into the code.

Comment: The theme I am using is "Hive" by pixelgrade (https://pixelgrade.com/themes/blogging/hive/). I don't appear to be using an SEO plugin and the theme does not have custom settings for the title/tagline. Do you know which part of the theme's code controls the title/tagline?

Comment: @Rooney No, sorry, I don't know, which part of the code controls the title of the website - but the producers themselves recommend the seo plugin Yoast for that -> https://pixelgrade.com/docs/hive/faq/site-title-and-tagline-not-updating/